# Android login to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello guys I'm doing an simple login system in android to mysql database online. This is what I've tried so far:

**MainActivity:**

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        strUsername = etUsername.getText().toString();
        strPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

        try{
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
            + " = " + URLEncoder.encode(strUsername, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
            + " = " + URLEncoder.encode(strPassword, "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(url_login);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
            wr.write( data ); 
            wr.flush(); 

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
               sb.append(line);
               break;
            }

            Log.e("TAG", sb.toString());

            return sb.toString();


         }catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
         }


    }
```

PHP side:

```
<?php
// Connect to dbconnect.php
include('dbconnect.php');

// array for JSON response 
$response = array();

// username and password sent from form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];



$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT username, password FROM customer WHERE username = :username AND  password = :password');
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password ));


$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user = $result['username'];
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($affected_rows >= 1){
         $response["success"] = 1;
         // successfully inserted into database

     $response["message"] = "New record successfully created.";
         // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } 


?>
```

Sample record:

Username: admin
Password: admin

I tried to run this but it's getting a response: success: 0 which means not successful. What am I doing wrong in here? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to add the `password` column to your SELECT, as in `SELECT username, password FROM customer`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm still getting the same when I added password

Comment: Ok. And what about changing `if($affected_rows >= 1)` to `if($affected_rows > 0)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- same issue again

Comment: Instead of all of `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user = $result['username'];
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($affected_rows >= 1){` try this under your `execute...` --- `if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)` or see this answer where I got this from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620035/1415724

Comment: Plus you may need to bind your data using `bindParam` which you're not doing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you post that as answer? I can hardly see your code. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. If anybody downvotes it though, I'll delete it. I shouldn't see why though, but if it works, great.

Comment: Any luck with what I posted?

Comment: @Dunkey Check Your $username and $password if it correct then check this record is exists or not. i am seeing your php code is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### (*Comment to answer, as requested*)

Instead of all of this:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$user = $result['username']; 
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount(); 
if($affected_rows >= 1){
```

try this under your `$stmt->execute(array...` line

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
  { echo "Exists"; }
else { echo "Does not exist"; }
```

or see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620035/1415724) where I got this from.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

*PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a **SELECT** statement, **some** databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is **not guaranteed** for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.*

Check $result to see if you got a username or not.