# page will not die() if the person is banned php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<?php 
require_once('mysql_connect.php');
$query2 ="SELECT  id, username, banned FROM login WHERE username ='$login_session'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) OR die($mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($result2);

if($row['banned'] == 1) {
die();
}

?>
```

Session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: login.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

As you can see , im trying to stop people who are banned from loading profile.php

it doesnt stop the profile page from loading

Comment: so, where is `$login_session` being defined and how? this tells me you're probably using sessions. You're also using the wrong function for `$row`. Either use one that will fetch a row as an array, or change `if($row['banned'] == 1)` to `if($row == 1)`

Comment: If you had turned on error reporting you would see that `$row` is a number, not an array. You are treating it as an array and so it is not working as you expect. (Basically, what @Fred-ii- said - he beat me to it.)

Comment: Do you have a pre-set variable on the top of your given code? I assume that is a session variable that goes something like `session_start(); $login_session = $_SESSION["username"];`

Comment: here see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620252/

Comment: make it to an answer, ill mark as answered as soon as i can

Comment: @KIXEYE it has been done.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions. Migrate to MySQLi or PDO (best)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *thanks fred, that worked –  KIXEYE*
>
> *make it to an answer, ill mark as answered as soon as i can –  KIXEYE*

As per the OP's wish:

You're using the wrong function for `$row`. Either use one that will fetch a row as an array, or change `if($row['banned'] == 1)` to `if($row == 1)` to work with `mysql_num_rows`.

---

Footnotes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Example pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620252/

```
$user = "bob";
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM my_table WHERE username='{$user}' LIMIT 1;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row["num_rows"] > 0){
   //user exists
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If your `banned` row contains `1` or `0` to check if they're banned, then add another parameter to your `where` clause. I.e.: `WHERE username ='$login_session' AND banned !=1` if banned column is an `int` type. If not, wrap `1` in quotes.

- This translates to WHERE username exists and is 'John' and banned does NOT equal 1. Or make it `0`, it's your choice.

Comment: I just tried the answer you gave to me a moment ago uptop, now it shows the banned page even if your not banned.

This is what i tried.
`<?php 
require_once('mysql_connect.php');
$query2 ="SELECT  id, username, banned FROM login WHERE username ='$login_session'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) OR die($mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($result2);

if($row == 1) {
include 'banned.php';
} else {}

?>`
Banned.php
` <?php 
if($row == 1) {
echo'banned';
}
die();
?>`

Comment: @KIXEYE which piece of code in your question is `profile.php` the first one? What you should be doing then, is checking to see if the session is set in the page you want to protect. I.e.: `if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){ do something } else { do something else }`. All pages must contain that conditional statement which is best. But for the protected page mostly.

Comment: the session has to be set, otherwise profile.php redirects you back to login page.

Comment: @KIXEYE worked fine for me. I logged out and tried to reload profile.php and was not able to see the information I saw once logged in. I got ridirected to http://rs-list.com/login.php automatically because I wasn't signed in.

Comment: @KIXEYE now I just did it again and I now see `banned`. so something looks like it kicked in. Edit: now was able to see the content when I reloaded profile.php

Comment: displays as banned even tho the account has banned == 0 in the database  edit: Banned located to left corner of site

Comment: @KIXEYE are you using `if($row == 1)` or `if($row == 0)`? you wrote `even tho the account has banned == 0` try using `if($row >0 )` instead.

Comment: @KIXEYE if you're getting a "banned" echo'd message on top left (was black, hard for me to see it), then whatever content you're using for that page, isn't inside the right conditional statement. I don't think you showed us the full or more code that we need. Does your question contain code for `profile.php`? that's unclear. If session is set, show something, else show them something else, or "include" something else.

Comment: still says banned. Ill explain what im trying to do here,

If the username logged in , has "1" instead of "0" in the banned my strutcue = id, username,avatar,banned .

if the user is banned, echo banned die page.

Comment: will post it on pastebin so  u can see full code       

Profile.php http://pastebin.com/SCJeT4Um

session.php http://pastebin.com/geMGyTeQ

Comment: @KIXEYE if your `banned` row contains `1` or `0` to check if they're banned, then add another parameter to your `where` clause. I.e.: `WHERE username ='$login_session' AND banned !=1` if banned column in an `int` type. If not, wrap `1` in quotes. This say WHERE username='John' and does NOT equal 1. Or make it `0`, your choice.

Comment: @KIXEYE and the pastebin file contains `if($num == 1) {
include 'banned.php';
} ` I don't see `die()` or anything else to stop the process. You can also use a header redirect instead, if banned, rather than show page content and redirect them to `login.php` instead. and add `exit;` after the header to prevent further execution of code that may be below that. Edit: Saw your new comment, you're welcome. Will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Then why don't you just fetch user who are not banned:

```
$ses_sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='$user_check' AND banned <> 1",$connection);
$numofresult = mysql_num_rows($ses_sql);
```

Then check if it has a result:

```
if($numofresult > 0){
   /* SUCCESS */
}
else {
   /* BANNED */
}
```

To compromise [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($username,$connection);
```

But a better recommendation is to use `mysqli_* prepared statement` or PDO.

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='$user_check' AND banned <> 1")){
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $numofresult = $stmt->num_rows;
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: @HalfCrazed - it is because the OP uses `mysql_*`

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_num_rows()` returns *a number of rows*, not the rows themselves.

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or similar function.

Comment: No, you should not use any `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: @Half Crazed I did not say *must*, did I? Those are deprecated at 5.5, and will be removed in future, go hate somewhere else (oh, do you downvote OP as well?).