# pdo if rowcount is zero

Tags: php, pdo

I want to run a python script if the dans_code doesn't exist. i use the following code for this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=import", $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT dans_code from import where dans_code = ':code'");
$stmt->bindParam(':code', $dans);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
{
exec("C:\\Python34\\python.exe code.py $dans");
}
```

but when i run the script also the variables that exist in my database trigger the if statement. How is this possible? i m using a postgresdatabase I have this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620019/check-if-sql-row-exists-with-php)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wrap off quotes` form your placeholder just use

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT dans_code from import where dans_code = :code");
```

Other wise your where become `where dans_code='".'$dane'."'` and you always get 0 result