# Codeigniter trap the ID that does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

base on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620019/check-if-sql-row-exists-with-php) I came to with this code to make an **error message** if the ID does not exist

this is my code in **CI model**

```
public function user_list_update($id){
    $id = $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('info');
    $row = $query->row();
    if($row > 0){             //line 26
        return $row;
    }else{
        echo "does not exist.";
    }
}
```

and in the **controller**

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');
$data["user_list"] = $this->um->user_list_update($id);
//some code here to display data of ID
```

and I get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int
>
> Filename: models/users_model.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\models\users_model.php Line: 26
>   Function: _error_handler

P.S im new to C.I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 if($query->num_rows() > 0)
```

Instead of:

```
if($row > 0){
```

Comment: what is the difference of your answer sir to this? if(isset($row))

Comment: my answer check the number of rows  eg(rows = 5), while `if(isset($row))` checks if `$row` has something eg. ($row = "dsfdfdf")

Answer (score 1):

The result of `$row = $query->row();` is an object called `$row`

You cannot test an object against an integer it gives the error as you can see

So instead test that the `$row` variable is actually set

```
public function user_list_update($id){
    $id = $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('info');
    $row = $query->row();
    if(isset($row)){             //line 26
        return $row;
    }else{
        echo "does not exist.";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference of your answer to this? if($query->num_rows() > 0)

Comment: Not a lot of difference. This is the way suggested in the manual

Comment: Although if the query fails `$row` may not be an object, so using `$query->num_rows()` may also fail with a `not an object error`

Answer (score 1):

You can Used this solution for your problem:

```
public function user_list_update($id){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->from('info');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row;
    } else {
        echo "does not exist.";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.