# Select then Insert PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

Ho can I check the database first if a user exists then use a insert statement if it does not. The code currently only executes the select statement.

```
<?php
    include_once('includes/dbconn.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $query_check_user = "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
        $query = "INSERT INTO Users(firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$user','$pass')";

        if (mysqli_query($dbconn, $query_check_user)) {
            echo "user already exists";
            mysqli_close($dbconn);
        }else{
            mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if SQL row exists with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620019/check-if-sql-row-exists-with-php)

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns `false` only on failure, not just because it returns an empty set.

Comment: Please also look up prepared statements (your queries are prone to SQL injection).

Comment: mysqli_query returns a mysqli_result object for SELECT-queries and your task is to check if that object contains at least one row.

Comment: Performing a check if a record exists with `SELECT` is bad because it's not accurate information. By the time you're done checking, another process can insert that record and you can end up with 2 records that are the same. To fight this problem, we use `unique` constraints, we simply insert and if database reports `duplicate key error` then we know a record exists.

Comment: @N.B. Does that happens in a real world application where users registers and both queries (SELECT and INSERT) are ecxecuted that close? Theoretically YES, but your users have to do that by purpose and need a lot of luck. Therefore, I don't use unique constr. for usernames. Maybe a user deletes his account (and you only mark him as deleted in the db) then new users can't use that username.

Comment: @Flocke it's not a case of "does it happen", it's the case of creating a system where there are no holes such as this one. It might not happen today, tomorrow, in 6 months. What if it happens in 2 years? However, the interesting bit is that creating a unique constraint makes it easier for us as we have to type way, way less code. And it's bulletproof, forever. Regarding soft-deletes, you can always create a unique constraint out of `(username, is_deleted)` or hash `(username, is_deleted)` and save that as unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
    include_once('includes/dbconn.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        //Query for count
        $query_check_user = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
        $query = "INSERT INTO Users(firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$user','$pass')";
        //Execute query for count
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query_check_user);
        //Fetch result
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        //Check if count >0
        if ($data['total']>0) {
            echo "user already exists";
            mysqli_close($dbconn);
        }else{
            mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is vulnerable against sql injection attacks. Please teach proper techniques.

Comment: this is the output

0 if ($data['total']>0) { echo "user already exists"; mysqli_close($dbconn); }else{ mysqli_query($dbconn, $query); } } ?>

Answer (score -2):

you can use `mysqli_num_rows();` to check the number if result if it is greater then 0 then user exist else insert user data.

my example :

```
include_once('includes/dbconn.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $query_check_user = "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
        $query_result = mysqli_query($query_check_user);
        $query = "INSERT INTO Users(firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$user','$pass')";

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_result) > 0) {
            echo "user already exists";
            mysqli_close($dbconn);
        }else{
            mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: does not work. adds a user even if the username exists

Comment: check your query on phpmyadmin or show me your db structure of table username

Answer (score -3):

as I get from your question is, you want to insert the user if the user doesn't exist, right?

```
$query_check_user = "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
$b = mysqli_query($dbconn,$query_check_user);
$a = mysqli_num_rows($b);
if($a<0):
   mysqli_query(dbconn, "INSERT INTO Users(firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$user','$pass')");
endif;
```

Comment: Your answer is vulnerable against sql injection attacks. Please teach proper techniques.

Comment: you are trying to insert a new user if the user already exists - might be wrong

Comment: that edit does not help - number of rows wont be < 0